# struct in C++ which can be initialized with 0, but not with another int

Tags: c++

Pseudo-code:

```
struct Time {
    // constructor from zero
    constexpr T(const int i)
        : m_(i) {
            static_assert(i == 0, "Can only construct from zero");
        }

    // other constructors from seconds, microseconds, etc.

    int m_{};
};

int main() {
    T t1(0); // correct
    T t2(1); // incorrect

    return 0;
}
```

It is not a correct code (static_assert cannot compile with non-constant at compile time `i`). Can it be written in any another way?

UPD. I know about default constructors. This question is: Is it possible in C++ to statically check parameter in constructor.

Comment: If the only valid value is 0, why do you even make it a function parameter ? Juste make it a constructor without params

Comment: What the deuce? If something is always zero, then why not use `0`?

Comment: Wut? This is a very peculiar [Y, so what's the X to accompany it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: No you can not do compile-time checking of run-time values. It's impossible. And as just about everyone else I also wonder what the actual problem is? What led you to ask this question?

Comment: I guess the gist of the question is: is there any way to have the function parameter qualify to be a constant expression? (Obviously the function must only ever be called with constant expression argument)

Comment: If you write the constructor to take a `void*` instead of an `int` it will accept 0 but no other integer value. But, as others have said, what's the point?

Comment: @PeteBecker Just for language experiments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `decltype(nullptr)` (aka `std::nullptr_t`):

```
#include <iostream>

struct Time
{
    constexpr Time(decltype(nullptr)) {}

    int m_{};
};

int main() {
    Time t1(0);
    Time t2(1); // error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Time'

    return 0;
}
```

Note that this trick won't allow you to do `int x = 0; Time t1(x);`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `std::integral_constant`

```
struct S {
    constexpr S(std::integral_constant<int, 0> i)
        : m_(i) {
            static_assert(i == 0, "Can only construct from zero");
        }

    int m_{};
};

int main() {
    S t1(std::integral_constant<int, 0>{}); // correct
    //S t2(std::integral_constant<int, 1>{}); // incorrect
}
```

but as state in comment, why making thing complicated whereas you may simply initialize your member to 0 without that argument.

Comment: it's just a synthetic example, I wanted to learn is it possible, and if it is then how to do it. Your answer is perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Simply assign it to zero?

```
struct Time {
    // constructor from zero
    constexpr T(int i) //ignored
        : m_(0) {}    
}
```

Comment: But then I cannot write `T t1(0);`

Comment: Why do you need to construct it with a parameter different than zero, if you only accept zero as valid? If you really really really need to have a parameter in the func, but you can only have it 0 hen you can do so:
    `struct Time {

    // constructor from zero

    constexpr T(int i) //ignored

        : m_(0) {}    

    }`

I cannot insert code in comment, I'll edit the answer